# How to solve Ax=b when some values of x are known and b is vector of zeros

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix Q=A (64x64), a vector f=b is vector of zeros and I know some values of x=q. I know that I should transfer the corresponding column and row (of known x=q) on the right side of the equation (to b), but I don't know, how to make it in Matlab. I should to do that for **1st, 5th, 9th, 13th, 17th, 21st, 25th, 29th, 33th, 37th, 41st, 45th, 49th, 53th, 57th and 61st,** column and row. Can you help me, pls?

This is the program:

```
clear all;
K=zeros(64,64);
f=zeros(64,1);

ne=32;
E= 8000; %Young
P= 0.51; %Poisson

Lambda=(E*P)/((1+P)*(1-2*P));
Eta=E/(2*(1+P));

%ILOK
ILOK=[
1   3   5   7   2   4   6   8;
5   7   9   11  6   8   10  12;
9   11  13  15  10  12  14  16;
13  15  17  19  14  16  18  20;
17  19  21  23  18  20  22  24;
21  23  25  27  22  24  26  28;
25  27  29  31  26  28  30  32;
29  31  33  35  30  32  34  36;
33  35  37  39  34  36  38  40;
37  39  41  43  38  40  42  44;
41  43  45  47  42  44  46  48;
45  47  49  51  46  48  50  52;
49  51  53  55  50  52  54  56;
53  55  57  59  54  56  58  60;
57  59  61  63  58  60  62  64;
61  63  1   3   62  64  2   4;
3   0   7   0   4   0   8   0;
7   0   11  0   8   0   12  0;
11  0   15  0   12  0   16  0;
15  0   19  0   16  0   20  0;
19  0   23  0   20  0   24  0;
23  0   27  0   24  0   28  0;
27  0   31  0   28  0   32  0;
31  0   35  0   32  0   36  0;
35  0   39  0   36  0   40  0;
39  0   43  0   40  0   44  0;
43  0   47  0   44  0   48  0;
47  0   51  0   48  0   52  0;
51  0   55  0   52  0   56  0;
55  0   59  0   56  0   60  0;
59  0   63  0   60  0   64  0;
63  0   3   0   64  0   4   0;
];

%x
xm=[
9.000   14.500  8.315   13.396;
8.315   13.396  6.364   10.253;
6.364   10.253  3.444   5.549;
3.444   5.549   0.000   0.000;
0.000   0.000   -3.444  -5.549;
-3.444  -5.549  -6.364  -10.253;
-6.364  -10.253 -8.315  -13.396;
-8.315  -13.396 -9.000  -14.500;
-9.000  -14.500 -8.315  -13.396;
-8.315  -13.396 -6.364  -10.253;
-6.364  -10.253 -3.444  -5.549;
-3.444  -5.549  0.000   0.000;
0.000   0.000   3.444   5.549;
3.444   5.549   6.364   10.253;
6.364   10.253  8.315   13.396;
8.315   13.396  9.000   14.500;
14.500  20.000  13.396  18.748;
13.396  18.748  10.253  14.142;
10.253  14.142  5.549   7.654;
5.549   7.654   0.000   0.000;
0.000   0.000   -5.549  -7.654;
-5.549  -7.654  -10.253 -14.142;
-10.253 -14.142 -13.396 -18.748;
-13.396 -18.748 -14.500 -20.000;
-14.500 -20.000 -13.396 -18.748;
-13.396 -18.748 -10.253 -14.142;
-10.253 -14.142 -5.549  -7.654;
-5.549  -7.654  0.000   0.000;
0.000   0.000   5.549   7.654;
5.549   7.654   10.253  14.142;
10.253  14.142  13.396  18.748;
13.396  18.748  14.500  20.000;
];

%y
ym=[
0.000   0.000   3.444   5.549
3.444   5.549   6.364   10.253
6.364   10.253  8.315   13.396
8.315   13.396  9.000   14.500
9.000   14.500  8.315   13.396
8.315   13.396  6.364   10.253
6.364   10.253  3.444   5.549
3.444   5.549   0.000   0.000
0.000   0.000   -3.444  -5.549
-3.444  -5.549  -6.364  -10.253
-6.364  -10.253 -8.315  -13.396
-8.315  -13.396 -9.000  -14.500
-9.000  -14.500 -8.315  -13.396
-8.315  -13.396 -6.364  -10.253
-6.364  -10.253 -3.444  -5.549
-3.444  -5.549  0.000   0.000
0.000   0.000   5.549   7.654
5.549   7.654   10.253  14.142
10.253  14.142  13.396  18.748
13.396  18.748  14.500  20.000
14.500  20.000  13.396  18.748
13.396  18.748  10.253  14.142
10.253  14.142  5.549   7.654
5.549   7.654   0.000   0.000
0.000   0.000   -5.549  -7.654
-5.549  -7.654  -10.253 -14.142
-10.253 -14.142 -13.396 -18.748
-13.396 -18.748 -14.500 -20.000
-14.500 -20.000 -13.396 -18.748
-13.396 -18.748 -10.253 -14.142
-10.253 -14.142 -5.549  -7.654
-5.549  -7.654  0.000   0.000
];

%Ke a fe of element    
for k=1:ne
    x=xm(k,:);%k-ty radek x-ove matice
    y=ym(k,:);%k-ty radek y-ove matice

Au=zeros(4,4);
Av=zeros(4,4);
Auv=zeros(4,4);
Avu=zeros(4,4);

%Numerical integration
for i=1:9
    a=0.774596669241483;
    gaus=[1 0 0 68/81;
          2 0 a 40/81;
          3 a 0 40/81;
          4 0 -a 40/81;
          5 -a 0 40/81;
          6 a a 25/81;
          7 a -a 25/81;
          8 -a -a 25/81;
          9 -a a 25/81];

    r=gaus(i,2);   
    s=gaus(i,3);  
    N=[(1/4)*(1-r)*(1-s);
       (1/4)*(1+r)*(1-s);
       (1/4)*(1+r)*(1+s);
       (1/4)*(1-r)*(1+s)];

    Nr=[(1/4)*(s-1);
        (1/4)*(1-s);
        (1/4)*(s+1);
        (1/4)*(-s-1)];

    Ns=[(1/4)*(r-1);
        (1/4)*(-1-r);
        (1/4)*(r+1);
        (1/4)*(1-r)];

    %Jacob matrix
    j1=Nr'*x';
    j2=Nr'*y';
    j3=Ns'*x';
    j4=Ns'*y';
    J=[j1 j2;
       j3 j4];
    detJ=abs(det(J));
    invJ=inv(J);

    %Nx a Ny
    Nx=invJ(1,1)*Nr+invJ(1,2)*Ns;
    Ny=invJ(2,1)*Nr+invJ(2,2)*Ns;

    ds=gaus(i,4)*detJ;        

    Au=Au+(Nx*(Lambda*Nx'+2*Eta*Nx')+Eta*Ny*Ny')*ds;
    Av=Av+(Ny*(Lambda*Ny'+2*Eta*Ny')+Eta*Nx*Nx')*ds;
    Auv=Auv+(Nx*Lambda*Ny'+Eta*Ny*Nx')*ds;
    Avu=Avu+(Ny*Lambda*Nx'+Eta*Nx*Ny')*ds;

    Ke=[Au Auv;
        Avu Av];
    fe=zeros(8,1);
end

%K a f
N=8;
je=1:N;
mg(je)=ILOK(k,je);
igl=mg;
inen=find(igl);
K(igl(inen),igl(inen))=K(igl(inen),igl(inen))+Ke(igl>0,igl>0);
f(igl(inen))=f(igl(inen))+fe(igl>0);

Ke=zeros(8,8);
fe=zeros(8,1);
end
K;
```

And then I need to solve q=K/f
I would like transfer the columns a rows from this matrix to **f** (in this case).
Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Can you provide us with your `x` vector? I can give a more specific solution if so. Otherwise, the general procedure I've provided should be sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known as solving for the **null space** of a matrix.

---

```
Z = null(A)
Z = null(A,'r')
```

> Z = null(A) is an orthonormal basis for the null space of A obtained
>   from the singular value decomposition. That is, A*Z has negligible
>   elements, size(Z,2) is the nullity of A, and Z'*Z = I.
>
> Z = null(A,'r') is a "rational" basis for the null space obtained from
>   the reduced row echelon form. A*Z is zero, size(Z,2) is an estimate
>   for the nullity of A, and, if A is a small matrix with integer
>   elements, the elements of the reduced row echelon form (as computed
>   using rref) are ratios of small integers.
>
> The orthonormal basis is preferable numerically, while the rational
>   basis may be preferable pedagogically.

Please refer to the fully worked out examples in the *References* section below, as they include MATLAB-specific examples, and worked out "by hand" solutions.

Good luck!

**References**

---

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/null.html

http://www.math.sunysb.edu/~badger/mat211f12/solver.pdf

Comment: Can I send you hole program? I have matrix A(64x64) and I need 'only' transfer 24 columns and rows on the right side of the equation (to b). Vector x is unknown, which I would like to get like: x=A\b...Can I send it here or to email?

Comment: In all cases, please post the whole thing on StackOverflow, so future readers can benefit from it. Second, are you writing an algorithm in MATLAB to solve for the null space, or do you just need the answer to this specific question? (ie: is this a mathematics or a programming question?)

Comment: Is programming and I need the procedure in Matlab. I know how to do it by hand on the paper. Okay, I will reedit the question ;)

Comment: I reedited it ;) Pls look at it ... copy to the Matlab and run it. Print K and I would like transfer the columns a rows from this matrix to f (in this case).

Comment: OK, so you're trying to implement a null space solver algorithm. Sorry, but the best I can provide is a link to the general procedure.